# Is there a way to convert PS1 .MCR save files to PSP .VMP format without using CWCheat?

Tags: psp, ps1

I'd like to know if there's a way to convert .MCR to .VMP without having to use CWCheat? I found MemCardRex but it only converts ***from*** .VMP to other formats but not other formats ***to*** .VMP.

Comment: Do you have this files on a computer drive or a PSX memory card?